# Will APIs in hiddenapi-greylist-max-o work in Android Pie?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I am upgrading my app to target Android SDK 28. To check for compatibility issues, I ran the veridex tool against the APK, and it says I am using 2 APIs in greylist-max-o.

Will these APIs work on a device running Android Pie? From the "o" in the name (greylist-max-o), it seems to imply that the APIs will only work up to Android Oreo.

```
./appcompat.sh --dex-file=./test.apk

78 hidden API(s) used: 52 linked against, 26 through reflection
       76 in greylist
       0 in blacklist
       2 in greylist-max-o
       0 in greylist-max-p
```

Comment: how can we find what are these 2 apis? and from where they are called?

Comment: @Haris The report also gives you a line like `#8: Reflection greylist-max-p Landroid/animation/LayoutTransition;->cancel use(s):
       Landroidx/transition/ViewGroupUtilsApi14;->cancelLayoutTransition(Landroid/animation/LayoutTransition;)V` for each API found. In my case, 99% were from the libraries that I use and not from my code.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption. Those APIs will only work if you target api level `27` (Android O and lower).

From the official documentation:

> If a non-SDK interface was part of the darkgrey list for Android 9 (API level 28), that interface is now part of the greylist-max-o list, where “o” stands for Oreo or Android 8.1 (API level 27). In this case, you would only be able to use an interface that belongs to the greylist-max-o list if your app targets Android 8.1 (API level 27) or lower.

See more here: https://developer.android.com/preview/non-sdk-q#list-name-changes

Comment: What happens when you target API level 27 on Android 9 (API level 28)? Do the calls work because the target API level is equal to the greylist-max-o or fail because the Android version is higher?

Comment: Also, will an existing app targeting API level 27 still work on Android 10, 11, or break out of nowhere? I am really confused about this.